# Fixing XSS security issue in php

Tags: php, security, xss

During security testing I am constantly getting Cross site scripting [stored] issue as-
URL encoded POST input textsize was set to Largest_935538'():;916159
The input is reflected inside `<script>` tag between single quotes.

Affected file- change.php

After tiresome efforts I could find any clue to resolve, PFB is code for your reference, can someone guide me on fixing this issue-

```
<?php
include("global/user_global.php");
session_cache_limiter('nocache');

$color_array    =   array("blue","brown","black","high","style");
if(isset($_SESSION["lang"]))
{
    if($_SESSION["lang"]=="hindi")


{
        $logo       =   array("logo_hindi_blue.png","logo_hindi_high.png");
    }
    else
    {
        $logo       =   array("logo_eng_blue.png","logo_eng_high.png");
    }
}
else
{
    $logo       =   array("logo_eng_blue.png","logo_eng_high.png");
}
$referer        =   "$master_url";

if(isset($_REQUEST["font_action"]))

{
    $theme              =   $_REQUEST["theme"];
    $textsize           =   $_REQUEST["textsize"];
    if ($textsize=="")
    {
        $_SESSION["fonts"]  =   "Medium";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["fonts"]  =   $textsize;
    }
    if($theme=="")
    {
        $_SESSION["theme"]  =   "style.css";    
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["theme"]  =   $theme.".css";
    }
}
else
{
    $theme          =   $_REQUEST["theme"];
    $lg             =   $_REQUEST["lg"];
    $found  =   in_array("$theme",$color_array);


if($found)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["theme"]))
        {
            $_SESSION["theme"]      =   $theme.".css";
            $_SESSION["logo"]       =   $logo[$lg];
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION["theme"]      =   "style.css";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["theme"]      =   "style.css";
    }
}
header("Location: $master_url");
exit();
?>
```

Comment: just check all inputs carefully

Comment: Bro,pls don't be generic be specific. Solution to this could be most common sense but had sleepless nights since few days & yet to resolve. Do a favor & point it out, thnx :)

Comment: the only XSS vulnerability here is that a hacker can change "blue", "brown", and the different CSS colors. whatever is giving you that XSS warning doesn't understand that you're actually VALIDATING the css url with in_array("$theme",$color_array);

Comment: This PHP is a nightmare, use a template.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the security test is noticing that you use `$_REQUEST['theme']` to select the CSS file that you use, and this seems like a XSS vulnerability. But you validate this input using `in_array("$theme",$color_array);`, so only valid CSS files can be selected. This should mitigate the vulnerability, and apparently the security check didn't recognize this.

However, you don't have any validation when you do `$_SESSION['fonts'] = $textsize;`. Maybe this is the source of the validation error. I'm not sure how much damage someone can do by supplying an erroneous font size, but it depends on how you use this session variable.